# How to show name of company with orders in query?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the name of the company to show on top of each group that contains OrderDate and the Total made, for example:

> Ray's Company
>
> 11/1/1996 12:00:00 AM
>
> 2296.00
>
> Jay's Company
>
> 3/10/1997 12:00:00 AM
>
> 956.68
>
> Bee's Company
>
> 11/13/1997 12:00:00 AM
>
> 1416.00

I have only been able to show the OrderDate and Total, but not the company's name. Would like to know how I could show the company's name as well. Here is what I have thus far:

```
static void Exercise21()
    {
        List<Customer> customers = DataLoader.LoadCustomers();

        var companys = (from y in customers
                       group y by y.CompanyName into newCompany
                       select newCompany).ToList(); //this is company name

        var customersSort = (from customer in customers
                             from x in customer.Orders
                            group x by x.OrderDate into newGroup
                            select newGroup).ToList();

        string line = "{0,-35}";
        Console.WriteLine(line, "Category");
        Console.WriteLine("======================================================================================");

        foreach (var customerGroup in customersSort)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(customerGroup.Key);

            foreach (var customer in customerGroup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line, customer.Total);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well.. your sample and desired output don't seem to necessitate the `GroupBy` here.  `total` isn't derived by it in your sample.  potentially, you just want `Distinct` on the orders here? having said that, without the desired output and with possibility of using another property on the GroupedOrders would merit this GroupBy approach..

Comment: You're making no effort to output anything from `companys`, which your code comment says `//this is company name`. Shouldn't doing so solve your problem?

Comment: well.. hmm.. I see that I may be mistaken regarding the `Total`, it is on `Orders` right?...  but I'm not sure this code is handling it properly or as you desire it to be.  For it will enumerate each total of the orders in a company.  so you do need a GroupBy on orders, to sum the totals.

Comment: yes Total comes from Orders, will it be helpful if I show LoadCustomers.cs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To address your question and consideration, the company name needs to output in the iteration.  You can handle this by ensuring you are handling your grouping in the context of iterating through the `List<Customer>` sequence.  This can be done in the foreach-loop or in the expression (referenced to as the alternative in this answer.

So, there are a couple implementations you can do here but reflect the same notion: grouping in the context of iterating.

In the following one I'm going to represent handling the lambda linq expressions in the context of iterating with the foreach-loop on `List<Customer> Customers`.

#### Type definitions and *DataLoader.LoadCustomers()* Mock

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public double Total { get; set; }
}

static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomersMocks()
{
    return new List<Customer>
    {
        new Customer
        {
             CompanyName = "Ray's Company",
             Orders = new List<Order>
             {
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("11/1/1996 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 1148},
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("11/1/1996 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 1148}
             }
        },
        new Customer
        {
             CompanyName = "Jay's Company",

             Orders = new List<Order>
             {
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("3/10/1997 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 478.34 },
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("3/10/1997 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 478.34 }
             }
        },
        new Customer
        {
             CompanyName = "Bee's Company",
             Orders = new List<Order>
             {
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("11/13/1997 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 708 },
                 new Order { OrderDate = DateTime.Parse("11/13/1997 12:00:00 AM"), Total = 708 }
             }
        }
    };
}
```

#### Sample

```
static void Exercise21()
{
    //List<Customer> customers = DataLoader.LoadCustomers();

    var customers = GetCustomersMocks();

    string line = "{0,-35}";
    Console.WriteLine(line, "Category");
    Console.WriteLine("======================================================================================");

    foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(customer.CompanyName);
        var groupedOrdersList = (from c in customer.Orders group c by c.OrderDate);
        foreach (var groupedOrders in groupedOrdersList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(groupedOrders.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(line, (from g in groupedOrders select g.Total).Sum());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Console Output

[image: Console Output]

---

Here is an alternative that uses `.SelectMany` and `GroupBy`.

```
var groupedCustomerByCompanyNameOrderDate = customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders.Select(o => new { c.CompanyName, o.OrderDate, o.Total }))
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.CompanyName, c.OrderDate });

foreach (var g in groupedCustomerByCompanyNameOrderDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.CompanyName);
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key.OrderDate);
    Console.WriteLine(g.Sum(o => o.Total));
}
```

In the code above, your selecting (projecting to) an anonymous type and flattening the `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` Result to `IEnumerable<T>` (though it is deferred execution). You then perform a `GroupBy` on that sequence and iterate with one foreach loop (without nesting another foreach loop).

see `Enumerable.SelectMany` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Note: I don't typically use lambda, so there may be a means to `.Sum()` in that form.

Comment: I'm going to update this with the `.SelectMany` then `.GroupBy` alternative, to show how you can flatten this hierarchy to an anonymous type that will facilitate doing this output in 1 foreach-loop.